# Magento 1.9 add a static block only shown on startpage

Tags: magento, static, magento-1.9.1

I want to add a static block in my footer.

when I put this code into my header.phtml it will work in the header:

```
<code>
<?php
$is_homepage = Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage();
if($is_homepage)
{
echo "Dies ist die Homepage!";
} else {
echo "Dies ist NICHT die Homepage!";
}
?>
</code>
```

but when I want to put this code in the footer.phtml it wouldn’t work. What could be the problem?

I need a easy way to display my seo text on start page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check, page is homepage then you can use this condition

```
<?php 
    if(Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home'  && 
       Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms')
    {
    //condition
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Footer you can also use this code but don't forget to remove your cache from the Magento admin to see the changes.

```
<?php
$homepage = Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage();
if($homepage)
{
    echo "Homepage!";
} else {
    echo "NOT on Homepage!";
}
?>
```

Or if you only wants to display that particular static blocks on the home page footer just call it through the Home Page resources. For this navigate to the CMS > Pages > Select Home Page and Click on the Design from the left side bar and put the code here i.e.

```
<reference name="footer"> 
    <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml"> 
        <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/> 
        <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/> 
        <block type="cms/block" name="custom_footer_block"> 
            <action method="setBlockId"> 
                <block_id>custom_footer_block</block_id> 
            </action> 
        </block> 
    </block> 
</reference>
```

Hope it helps,

Thanks